# How to export grid data to PDF in ext.net

Tags: ext.net, export-to-pdf

I want to know how to export grid data to PDF in ext.net.
How can i do that?

I have seen many sites but all is related to asp.net.
I didn't get any content related to ext.net.

Answer (score 0):

Ext.NET can't export grid data to PDF, BUT you can use any solution what you find for ASP.NET application, because Ext.NET is ASP.NET Framework.

Comment: Done. I have included itextsharp.dll file